# Гриды. Как сделать, чтобы картинки были на одном уровне между друг другом и даже при разных разрешениях экрана?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-grid

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Roderen/ladesign/blob/main/index.html

Вот как нужно - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g9CQ.jpg
Вот как сейчас - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLqed.jpg

Может подскажите что использовать (мб у гридов что-то есть). grid-gap и магрин и паддинг не подходит, так как при смене разрешения всё опять криво.
И не только здесь, а ещё и снизу последний ряд.

Comment: `img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте к `<img>` свойство `display:block`

Comment: неа---------------------------------

Comment: @Dunker если нужно пиксель в пиксель, добавьте height: 100%. https://imgur.com/tGalyM7

Comment: Ахахаха! Только добавил height: 100%; и через минуту ты пишешь тоже самое хд
Всё равно спасибо) помогло хейт